# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia shows black screen in ios devices

Tags: javascript, html, video

The screen shows blank in ios devices when the stream displayed on the html5 video tag, it shows black screen. but work fines everywhere on other devices. Here is the js code

it works in single screen but when peer to peer js called for twillio it shows a black screen while video session starts between two devices and user

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then(function(stream) {
                 document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute('autoplay', '');
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute('muted', '');
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute('playsinline', '');   
                      
        document.getElementById("myVideo").srcObject = stream;
   document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
   
   }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
    alert(error.name + ": " + error.message);
    
  });
```

Here Is the HTML code

```
<video id="myVideo" allow="camera;microphone" class="silhouetteVideo" style="" autoplay playsinline controls="false"></video>
```

Comment: Please let me know if anyone has the solution

Comment: which browser and which ios device?

Comment: Safari on ios11,12,13  and iphone 6,7,8

Comment: I tried on Iphone 11/ios 14 beta, it works. Also works on 6s/ios 13.

Comment: Yes it works in single screen but when peer to peer js called for twillio it shows black screen while video session starts between two devices and users

Comment: Please update your question as it’s misleading...

Comment: Please provide a usable example that demonstrates the problem. There aren't enough details currently provided.

Comment: Are you trying with https://? Have you tried on Android devices?

Comment: Why are not you using Twilio SDK itself

`<div id="local-media"></div>`

`Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then((track) => {
        const localMediaContainer = document.getElementById("local-media");
        localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
});`

similarly for remote media when other peer joins.

Answer (score 0):

Safari iOS requires the web app to explicitly require permission of such medias.
You need to define the usage permission of camera in the manifest file, one such example is:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "permissions": {
    "audio-capture": {
      "description": "Required to capture audio using getUserMedia()"
    },
    "video-capture": {
      "description": "Required to capture video using getUserMedia()"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, reference the manifest file in your `index.html`

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

Comment: Could you provide a reference to this information please.